# Conflict between personal and work accounts

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

We are currently on the free tier.

Team users experience issues reaching/joining the Stack Overflow for Teams team (they keep getting redirected to the login page, even though they are already logged in) when they are *also* logged into their personal StackOverflow account.

We tell our users to always log out from their personal Stack Overflow account before going to Stack Overflow for Teams. As you can imagine this experience is somewhat clunky.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I thought having multiple accounts was [frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35607/383262). I have multiple logins (personal account and work account) for the same stack account.

Comment: @Jofre The answer you linked says "It is not a problem to have multiple accounts". There are perfectly legitimate reasons for having more than one account. Unfortunately, there are also a variety of things you can do with more than one account that are not permitted, and which will result in sanctions being imposed. If someone is using two different accounts to *just* keep work and personal separate, that's fine, unless the user is having the accounts interact, or using them to evade system or moderator imposed restrictions (it's a bit more complex than that, but that's the basic point).

Comment: @Makyen Yeah, not forbidden, but not encouraged. I was wondering if there was anything special with teams that might force you to use a different account.

Comment: @Jofre I don't think it's discouraged as long as you don't use them to abuse the system. See [this more detailed answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/348196) to the dup. The TL;DR rule is _"if the second account allows you to do something on the site that your normal account would be prevented from doing, it is abuse"_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Use, at least, different browser profiles to separate work and personal activities.

Maintaining multiple accounts on the same website is one of the things for which browsers have the capability to use multiple profiles/"people". At least for both Chrome and Firefox, setting up additional profiles/"people" is fairly easy, and should be something which people *routinely* do to keep personal and work browsing separate, if they aren't using stronger means to separate work and personal activities.

- Chrome: [Add a new profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?visit_id=637625676667888873-2477248087&rd=1#7110673)
- Firefox: [Profile Manager - Create, remove or switch Firefox profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles)

##### Really should use stronger separation between work and personal activities

There are, for *both* the company and the individual, *substantial*, complex issues, including, at least, security, privacy, and liability issues, with mixing personal and work activities on the same machine. What these issues are and the rights/responsibilities/liability for the company and individual vary quite a bit from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. It is in *both* the company's and the individual's best interest to keep these activities as separate as possible.

Employees and contractors should really be using separate machines for personal and work activities, ideally in different locations, or different designated areas (e.g. separate desks in a work from home environment). If they don't do that, then they should use separate virtual machines on the same physical device. If they don't do that, then separate browser profiles, at the *very* least.

##### Separating personal and work activities:

In descending order of effective separation:

1. Use separate machines: one owned by the company; one owned by the individual. Ideally, the machines would be in different locations, at least clearly designated areas for the two activities.
2. Use different virtual machines on the same physical machine.
3. Use (these two have about the same level of effective separation)

   - Different browsers on the same machine
   - Different profiles in the same browser: Profiles are, generally, implemented such that the profiles are accessed by separate processes, so there's no sharing of data between them.
4. The user's browser may have "containers", which are, generally, a lesser separation than profiles.
5. Temporarily use an "incognito"/"private" window or tab within the same browser profile as is primarily used for the other type of activity.

Comment: This is all fine advice, but it does not seem to answer the question as I understand it, which is pointing out a bug in Teams where people experience issues using it while logged into their personal accounts. I would be very unhappy if I suddenly had to juggle multiple accounts, browser profiles, computers, or what have you, simply due to a bug in the implementation of Teams. I have no other need for this.

Comment: @CodyGray The question asks for "Is there a better way?" than instructing the company's employees to log out of a personal SO account prior to using Teams. That *strongly* implies the users are using two separate accounts: one personal account and another account, which is for use with the company's SO for Teams area. How they are *actually* trying to handle this, or what is *really* going on isn't clear from the question, but the question appears to be wanting some separation between a personal SO account and the account used for Teams. This answer addresses how to maintain that separation.

Comment: A lot of us use Teams with our normal SO account and are not experiencing any issue along the lines which the OP has described. In fact, SO for Teams is designed with fairly strong integration with whatever SO account is in use by the user (more so than many would desire, but as much as is desired by others). If the OP's issue *isn't* related to keeping separation between accounts, then the question should be updated to include enough information to qualify as an MRE/MCVE in order to duplicate the issue they are having.

Answer (score -1):

There are several options available to make things easier.

1. Use multiple browsers e.g. Firefox for personal and Chrome for work or vice versa.
2. Use incognito mode on a single browser for personal access and standard mode (or incognito mode again) for the other account. Then a single browser will allow multiple different logins. You just switch between browser windows to switch in that case.
3. As [Larnu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) suggests: If you're using Firefox, just use its in-built [containers](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/containers) feature.

Comment: If you're using Firefox, just use it's in built containers feature (pretty sure it comes shipped with it now, but you can install the [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) manually). No need to open Chrome too then. :)

Comment: @Larnu thanks, I've incorporated that suggestion too.

Comment: Both Chrome and Firefox have the capability to use multiple browser profiles. Chrome calls these "people", while Firefox calls them "profiles". Keeping things like work and personal activities separate is one of the things for which that capability exists.